# Font TeX Gyre Termes Unable to Use

Tags: fonts, fontspec, small-caps, installing-fonts, tex-gyre-math

I am using the newest editions of MacOS, MacTeX, TeXMaker, and all the packages that I am using.

This is the code I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{tex-gyre}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{SiouanAdpositions.bib}

\title{Blah Blah Blah}
\author{Noah Blah Blah\\[.4cm]{Supervisory Professor: Dr. Blah Blah}}
\date{October 5th, 2020}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{forest}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[mcolblock]{leipzig}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
asdf
\end{document}
```

I have also tried not using \usepackage{tex-gyre}
I have tried manually downloading the font and putting it in the local tex folder, etc.

This is the error it gives me when I *do* include \usepackage{tex-gyre}:

! LaTeX Error: File `tex-gyre.sty' not found.

When I try installing this:

[image: tex-gyre.sty attempted installation]

However, it seems the package is definitely loaded:

[image: tex-gyre package installation]

This is the error it gives me when I *do not* include \usepackage{tex-gyre}:

! Package fontspec Error: The font "TeX Gyre Termes" cannot be found.

Thank you so much for your time and help!

EDIT: I also tried adding \usepackage{tg-termes} which resulted in:

! Package fontspec Error: The font "TeX Gyre Termes" cannot be found.

Result of running those two commands:

[image: result of commands]

Comment: You definitely don’t need `\usepackage{tex-gyre}`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Unfortunately, it still gives me the "! Package fontspec Error: The font "TeX Gyre Termes" cannot be found." error without it.

Comment: Since you say you’re on MacTeX, try running `sudo tlmgr install tex-gyre`.

Comment: It didn’t autodetect that you needed the package when you tried loading it with `\setmainfont`.

Comment: @Davislor texlive never auto-detects that packages are needed (unlike miktex)

Comment: @Davislor Every time I try that it just gives me this: noahcoen@Noahs-MacBook-Pro-2 LaTeX_Paper_Draft % sudo tlmgr install tex-gyre
Password:
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr install: package already present: tex-gyre
noahcoen@Noahs-MacBook-Pro-2 LaTeX_Paper_Draft %

Comment: Okay, does `kpsewhich texgyretermes-regular.otf` find anything?

Comment: If the file is there, you might want to run `sudo fc-cache -f -s -v` and `sudo luaotfload-tool -f -u -p -v` to make sure it’s in the caches.

Comment: @Davislor I posted a screenshot of it in the question. I think this is getting us somewhere! It seems to have found the font, but I cannot tell from the screenshot if that means it is still loading the second command? (because I can type new commands now and it has been a while)

Comment: You should be trying to install `tex-gyre`, not `tex-gyre.sty`.  There is no such file or package as `tex-gyre.sty`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, technically, you’re telling me what I said was correct? ;)

Comment: If `tlmgr` thinks the package was installed, but it isn’t correctly installed, try running `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` and `sudo tlmgr install --reinstall tex-gyre`.

Comment: Also, you don’t have a second TeX installation on your system, do you?

Comment: @Davislor I ran both of those and they both ran successfully, but I get this error when I put \usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} in the preamble: "! Package fontspec Error: The font "TeX Gyre Termes" cannot be found."

Comment: What does `kpsewhich texgyretermes-regular.otf` tell you? `fc-match "TeX Gyre Termes"`?

Comment: The first tells me: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyretermes-regular.otf and the second tells me: sudo: fc-match: command not found when I run it with "sudo" and: zsh: command not found: fc-match when I run it without sudo. Thank you for all your help!!

Comment: you can use  `\setmainfont{texgyretermes-regular.otf}` if fc-config isn't finding it by name

Comment: @DavidCarlisle et voila! It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To preemptively fix the problems you’ll get if you try `\setmainfont{texgyretermes-regular.otf}`, here is the recommended way to load the font:

```
\setmainfont{texgyretermes}[
  UprightFont = *-regular ,
  BoldFont = *-bold ,
  ItalicFont = *-italic ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic ,
  Extension = .otf ,
  Scale = 1.0 ]
```

This tells `fontspec` what filenames to search for.  If the italic font were named something like `texgyretermes-mediumitalic.ttf`, you would instead write `ItalicFont = *-mediumitalic , Extension = .ttf`.

I don’t have MacTeX to test on.  On another OS, I would tell you to first reinstall the package with

```
sudo tlmgr update --self --all
sudo tlmgr install --reinstall tex-gyre
```

Then rebuild the font caches XeTeX and LuaTeX use with

```
sudo fc-cache -f -s -v
sudo luaotfload-tool -f -u -p -v
```

If you have some out-of-date files in the TeX Live subdirectory of your user folder, maybe clear those out.

Another solution would be to run `sudo nano ${kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL}/fonts/TeXGyreTermes.fontspec` to create a configuration file in your local TeX tree, and edit it to have the following contents:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[TeXGyreTermes]{
  UprightFont = texgyretermes-regular.otf ,
  BoldFont = texgyretermes-bold.otf ,
  ItalicFont = texgyretermes-italic.otf ,
  BoldItalicFont = texgyretermes-bolditalic.otf ,
  Ligatures = Common
}
```

This should enable commands like `\setmainfont{TeXGyreTermes}` even if your installation is not able to look up the font by its display name.

Answer (score 0):

@DavidCarlisle and @Davislor answered the question in the comments.

What eventually worked for me was completely updated the entire TeXLive Manager, reinstalling TeX Gyre Termes, and then, instead of using \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}, I used \setmainfont{texgyretermes-regular.otf}.

Thank you everyone for your help!!!